# Global variable’s properties’ scope

Tags: javascript

Let’s say we have a global variable defined as follows:

```
gContainer = {};
gContainer.person = {
   name: "Jack",
   last_name: "Tompson"
};
```

Are its properties global too? I mean, is `person` global too?

Comment: `gContainer` is not a global var...

Comment: I have defined it as global

Comment: @bitoiu: How do you know it isn’t?

Comment: @bitoiu lets think that I have defined it in a way that it is global

Comment: @bitoiu : got you ! because of var keyword ?

Answer (score 5):

No. The term “global” only applies to variables, and `gContainer.person` is not a variable; it’s a property of an object.

Comment: Although, keep in mind, that they can still be accessed by everything. So, in a sense, it is "global" because it's globally available, because it is the property of a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Are its properties global too? I mean, is person global too?

No. `gContainer.person` is a property to an object not a global variable

Comment: even if gContainer is a global variable but its property is not ? Am I right?

Comment: @WaterfrVilla:- global is used in context of variables. When you say that gContainer.person then it is not a variable, it is property

Comment: @WaterfrVilla:- I am not sure but I think you will find this helpfull, [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)